# Integers from a list

Tags: python, list, set

I need to get the same integer: positive and negative from a list for example if the list consisted of [0,1,-1,3] it would just return 1 -1. so far I have.

```
s = []
for i in a:
    if i in s
        s.append(i and -i)
print s
```

Comment: You need a `:` at the end of that if statement.

Comment: At least two people in your class asked the same question yesterday. One of them had working (but slow) code; the other one had code that was close to working; both got lots of answers.

Comment: Here's [the other one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32496/how-would-i-optimize-this-code).

Comment: thank you abarnert you are a kind gentleman

Answer (score 4):

Let's translate this from English to Python directly.

First, we have to get the English description precise: You want all the values that are in `a`, whose negation is also in `a`.

In Python, that's:

```
[value for value in a if -value in a]
```

---

However, if you have a million values, that `-value in a` is going to have to search on average half a million values for each one, which means half a trillion total comparisons. One of your fellow students apparently turned that in, and got dinged for taking over a minute on some example data when it should have taken about a second.

You can fix that by using a `set`. Looking for a value in a set just takes a single hash lookup and a single comparison, instead of having to compare against every value. So:

```
s = set(a)
[value for value in a if -value in s]
```

---

There are various ways to optimize things further. Most obviously, if you don't need to preserve duplicates or to return the values in order, you can just iterate over the set instead of the original list. But there are other clever ideas. You can see a bunch of them [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32496/how-would-i-optimize-this-code), along with some comparisons.

Comment: Thanks man it worked well for me, and it comes out in the same order.

Answer (score 3):

To get only the pair of numbers, that have both positive and negative counter parts, you can use list comprehension like this:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, -1, 3]
>>> 
>>> [val for val in a if -val in a]
[0, 1, -1]
```

Note that you will also get `0`, as expected. If you don't want that, add an explicit check for that too.

Answer (score 2):

Loop Solution:

```
s = []
for i in a:
    if -i in a:
        s.append(i)

print s
```

Filter Solution:

```
s = filter(lambda x: -x in s, s)
```

List Comprehension Solution:

```
[x for x in s if -x in s]
```

Look carefully your solution. If you try to append -i and i at the same time, you will add duplicated values. Also, as @kindall mentioned, you should use list a in both for loops.

Here it is a performance benchmark on the solutions:

Here it is a performance benchmark of the solutions:

[image: performance]

I must say that the for loop surprised me...

PS: The answers are for python 2.7. In python 3 map, filter, etc. are lay, and you have to use something like list(filter(lambda x: -x in s, s)) in order to evaluate them.

Comment: This won't work. The only way to add a number to `s` is if it already contains its opposite, which it won't because it starts off empty.

Comment: Yes. I copied the original code and missed that.

Comment: This is going to be quadratic. One of yesterday's students wrote [effetively this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32496/how-would-i-optimize-this-code), but a bit more verbose, and it took over a minute on their test data instead of about a second.

Comment: I ran the solutions here, and your links solution were much slower than the rest. I got:

filter solution: 2.14 nanoseconds
for solution: 1.44 nanoseconds
list comprehension solution: 2.2 nanoseconds
negated func solution: 5.63 nanoseconds

Didnt expected the for solution to be so quick

Comment: @LucasRibeiro: If you're using Python 3, `filter` doesn't actually do _any_ work; it builds an iterator that will do the work _later_, when you iterate it. Try `list(filter(lambda x: -x in s, s))` to see how slow it is.

Comment: @LucasRibeiro: Also, you realize those are microseconds, not nanoseconds, right?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for correcting me. It is actually micro seconds (10^-6).

Filter are lazy in python3, but i'm using python 2.7 here. It's a good idea to mention this in the answer.

Comment: @LucasRibeiro: So when you were comparing it to the other solutions, you were off by a factor of 1000. Try `%timeit filter(lambda x: -x in a, a)` against `s = set(a)` then `%timeit filter(lambda x: -x in s, a)` and get the units right, and it's not a little bit faster, it's 900x slower. (Also, if you're testing against the 4-element list, that's kind of pointless. If the other poster was dinged for taking over a minute, the teacher is clearly using longer test inputs than that. And in real life, nobody cares about performance on 4 elements.)

Answer (score -2):

I haven't seen how index is implemented, but in all likelihood this is a O(n^2) solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

l = [ 1, 2 , -1 , 3]

for i in l:
    try:
        k = l.index(-1 * i )
        print i
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
```

Better approach would be the following:

1. Sort the list: nlogn
2. Then for each element in the list do a binary search for the negative of the current element. You can run a for loop for that. If you get a hit print the element. This will be nlogn too.

So, you will accomplish what you need in nlogn time.

Comment: Wrong how? An explanation of what's wrong might help people learn.

Comment: all it printed was this from -8 is
3 is
3
-6 is
5 is
5
-5 is
-5
9 is
1 is
3 is
3
-3 is
-3
3 is
3
1 is
-2 is
-2
9 is
-2 is
-2
1 is
-2 is
-2
0 is
0
2 is
2
-8 is
0 is
0

Comment: This doesn't generate the output the OP asked for, or even output that's easy to interpret. If you read the code carefully, you can figure out that `-8 is` means nothing, but `-8 is` followed by `-8` on a separate line means that `-8` should be in the list… but that's not exactly useful.

Comment: Sorry guys, I fixed it.

Comment: That first sentence is misleading. It's guaranteed to be quadratic, because there's no way list.index could possibly be implemented that wouldn't be linear.